# how to add checkbox into array inside object in angular?

Tags: angularjs

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="formData.week[]" ng-true-value="'Tuesday'">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="formData.week[]" ng-true-value="'Wednesday'">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="formData.week[]" ng-true-value="'Thursday'">
```

i want to store values in formData in week array,how to do help.how to store checkbox values into array in this format

Comment: Can you explain what you are  trying to do here and what you tried so far?

Comment: i want to store the checkbox values into an aaray.

Comment: How many day checkbox?

Comment: Why the answer was evaluated wrong? does not solve what you want?

Comment: Hi abhi, I made some changes in my answer by creating an array of the checkboxes. You can see the array in console. Please check and let me whether that answers your question or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope){
  
  $scope.formData = {}
  $scope.formData.week = [
    'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday','Saturday', 'Sunday'
  ];
  
  // code to store checkbox values into array
  var chkboxes = [];
  var c = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        if (c[i].type == 'checkbox') {
            chkboxes.push(angular.element(c[i]).attr('ng-true-value'));
        }
    }
  console.log(chkboxes);
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="formData.week[1]" ng-true-value="Tuesday">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="formData.week[2]" ng-true-value="Wednesday">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="formData.week[3]" ng-true-value="Thursday">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-click

```
<div ng-repeat = "day in days">
     <input type="checkbox" value={{day}} ng-click="toggleItems(day);">{{day}}
</div>
```

and in the controller

```
$scope.days = ['Monday','Tuesday',...];
$scope.formData = {week: []};
$scope.toggleItems= function(day){
   var index = $scope.formData.week.indexOf(day);
    if(index == -1) $scope.formData.week.push(day);
    else $scope.formData.week.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
 <div ng-repeat="day in formData.week">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="day.value" for="day.name" />
      <span>{{day.name}}</span>
 </div>
```

Initialize your week array at page load.

JS:

```
  $scope.formData = {
    week: [{
      name: "Monday",
      value: false
    },    {
      name: "Tuesday",
      value: false
    },{
      name: "Wednesday",
      value: false
    },{
      name: "Thursday",
      value: false
    },{
      name: "Friday",
      value: false
    },{
      name: "Saturday",
      value: false
    },{
      name: "Sunday",
      value: false
    }]
  };
```

Answer (score -1):

**HTML**

```
<label ng-repeat="role in roles">
  <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="user.roles" checklist-value="role.id"> {{role.text}}
</label>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["checklist-model"]);
app.controller('Ctrl2', function($scope) {
  $scope.roles = [
    {id: 1, text: 'guest'},
    {id: 2, text: 'user'},
    {id: 3, text: 'customer'},
    {id: 4, text: 'admin'}
  ];
  $scope.user = {
    roles: [2, 4]
  };
  $scope.checkAll = function() {
    $scope.user.roles = $scope.roles.map(function(item) { return item.id; });
  };
  $scope.uncheckAll = function() {
    $scope.user.roles = [];
  };
  $scope.checkFirst = function() {
    $scope.user.roles.splice(0, $scope.user.roles.length); 
    $scope.user.roles.push(1);
  };
});
```